# "and when" vs "until"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

> Just refresh the link, **and when** the judgement day arrives. Bang!
>
> Just refresh the link, **until** the judgement day arrives. Bang!

Which is correct here, *and when* or *until*?

Comment: It’s not perfectly clear to me what it is you’re trying to say, but I’ll point out a few things: 1. “refresh the link” has a pretty specific technical usage that you may not intend. Again, I'm not sure of the situation, but you may mean “refresh the page”. 2. The term “judgement day” should not have an article. 3. An exclamation point should not be followed by a full stop.

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to ELL! I've made some edits to your question to make it more appropriate for the site (we like to specifically refer to what part of the sentence we're asking about :)).

Comment: I'm building a web application that generates links of the user's result. The results will be displayed on a particular day that is not know. Hence, I refer to that day as Judgement Day. By using the word bang I want to convey hopefully once they view their results it would be a surprise. It would great if someone could come up with a better sentence. Thanks!

Comment: How about this? *Just keep refreshing (or clicking) the link until the Judgement Day arrives!*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Perfect! I'll use this one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, this is a punctuation problem.

Both can be grammatically correct, if we fixed the punctuation,

> *Sentence 1:*
> Just refresh the link. And, when the judgement day arrives... Bang!
>
> *Sentence 2:*
> Just refresh the link until the judgement day arrives. Bang!

Once fixed, sentence 1 sounds better. That *Bang!* in Sentence 2 seems to be a little dangling. (Is that *"Bang!"* for now, or for when the judgement day arrives?)

Then again, if you write any of your original sentences (without having punctuation fixed) in a chatroom, everyone would still know what you want to say.

Comment: The "Bang!" is when the judgement day(results) arrive. Any alternatives for That Bang! in Sentence 2 which would convey the same message?

Comment: To retain that *until*, I would say it like this: *Just refresh the link until the judgement day arrives. And, when it arrives, Bang!* Actually S2 is perfectly understandable but it is a little ambiguous. A shorter way might be *Just refresh the link until the judgement day arrives. Then... Bang!* Twisting the punctuation a bit, and might sound a little better than the original, *Just refresh the link until the judgement day arrives... Bang!*

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind. I have to keep the S2 as short and professional as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Until** tells us how long a situation continues. If something happens until a particular time, you stop doing it at that time.

The **Just refresh the link, until the judgement day arrives. Bang!** is the proper sentence in general. Because it indicates to wait for the judgement till it arrives.

And the second sentence indicates that the you perform the action first and as the result comes just do action. In this context the second sentence is correct.

It depends on you to in which context you are using the sentence.

Actually the **and when** are used in the context that you perform one action and immediately after that you are supposed to do another action without waiting for the result of your first action.

Comment: Thanks, you've made it crystal clear to understand.  
In The Sentence: 
Just refresh the link, until the judgement day arrives. Bang! What possible replacements could be done for the word 'Bang!'?

Comment: You can use the word Boom!. Catch! etc.. @Nick_inaw

Comment: You mean to say 
"Just refresh the link, until the judgement day arrives. Boom!"

Comment: Yes. This kind of words are slangs if you want to use you can use it just like that otherwise its fine.

Comment: I think I should drop the Bang! to keep it professional, shouldn't I?

Comment: That is also fine. If you drop it, it doesn't change the meaning.